# Use the graph to find the clues. Use the clues to name the movie star

Tags: letters

I like trying to invent new types of puzzles. I hope this one works.

---

[image]

[image]
**How to answer**

1. Using the graph, find the clues and say what they are.
2. Using the clues, name the star.
3. Explain how the diagram led you to the answer.
4. Use all the letters in the graph at least once (some of them twice or more often).

Comment: Something to do with finding a path that visits each node on the graph exactly once?

Comment: 1. There is no constraint on how many times you can visit a node However the structure indicates which nodes you *should* visit.  The circles are important as a focus. 2. I've now deleted the tag *graph theory*. It sounds too mathematical or high-powered.3. It is easier if you notice the colour scheme. However if anyone is colour-blind they can still do it.

Comment: Does this require knowledge of a language other than English?

Comment: No, only English. You're looking for clues to a movie.  Then name the star. You might perhaps start to guess it now but for a green tick you need to explain how the graph works,.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Matt Damon

How was this achieved:

> Looking at the groups connnected by red we get **JASNO**, which is an anagram for Jason.
>  Looking at the green we get **BUNOER** which anagrams to Bourne. 
>  Matt Damon famously played Jason Bourne. 
>  Maroon appears to anagram to Operation. 
>  And Blue anagrams to Treadstone **(thanks to Gordon K)**.  <sub>Don't anagram all loosey goosey kids</sub>

How the graph works:

> Anagrams are formed from the colour groupings. The colors have a node which is the circle, it is unique to that colour. Then then lines out from that color's node indicate the number of time the letter pair at the end (that isn't the node) appear in the anagram.

Comment: Excellent! +1 ---> This is nearly there. Note that there are two lines between two of the nodes. That is important. Your final word actually doesn't fit with the available letters. The actual final word relates to something much more relevant (and well-known) to the movie[s] in question. Can you redo that final word?

Comment: It's Treadstone.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I had not seen much of the movies to be honest and I was rushing out the door. Chasly, I used the t twice cause of the double lines in detonaters, (which was spelled wrong I think). Updated to reflect the help. Thanks mate.